# Session Timed Out - No Application ID US Visa

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, applications

I'm hoping someone could help me out. I was doing the online application (DS-160), however, the session timed out. I wasn't able to copy the application number nor save the application in time. The error message doesn't display the application ID as well, see below. Would it be fine if I make another application? I was around Part 2 or 3 of the security questions in the last part of the application.

[image]

Comment: okay-just got info that I can just make a new application as the old one wasn't saved.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment from the OP, the system will notify you that your old one wasn't saved, so it's safe to make a new application through the system, saving as you proceed this time.